# add html when drop down changes in a razor

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am trying to make a view where the user picks a golf course from a drop-down and the holes for that course appear when the course changes.

I have the following code in my view.

```
@model Golf_Statz.Models.Record

@{
  ViewBag.Title = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<script>
function DropDownChange(dd) {
    $('#CourseHoles').Empty();
    $('#CourseHoles').Html(@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RecordHoles));
    $('#CourseHoles').trigger('Create');
};    
</script>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Record</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.DatePlayed, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.DatePlayed, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.DatePlayed, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Score, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Score, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Score, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>

            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Course, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("Courses", null, "Select a Course", new { onchange="DropDownChange(this)"})
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Course, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="CourseHoles">

        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Basically the view for RecordHoles doesn't display. If I put an `alert` in the DropDownChange function it displays, so I at least know it is getting that far.

I have also put `@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RecordHoles)` inside a div, so I know the RecordHoles view works.

I think it might be a refresh issue, but to be honest that's just a guess.

This is my first mvc project so I have found it difficult searching for the correct terms. The closest thing I have managed to find is cascading drop-downs.

Comment: I think `Empty()` should be `empty()` and the same with `Html()`

Comment: Just tried, but the RecordHoles view still didn't display.

Comment: I dont think you can render a view through jQuery/JS.  You can pre-render the view in a hidden `<div>` and use `.show()` to show the div in this function.

Comment: @energ1ser, Not sure how that could possibly work (are you seriously going to render hidden views for every course in the dropdown?) You need to use ajax to call a controller method (passing the ID of the selected  course) which returns a partial view and then update the DOM.

Comment: @StephenMuecke fair point. I had decided that I would be able to figure the rest out from there. But after reading your partial view solution I'm not sure I could. Could you add yours as an answer - it's definitely a better one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 possible options to solve you issue

1. Use 2 separate forms, the first with just a dropdownlist displaying
   the courses, and in the post method, redirect to another method
   (passing the selected course ID) which displays all the holes for
   the course (and details such as date played etc)
2. Handle the `.change()` event of the dropdownlist and use ajax to
   update the DOM based on the selected course ID, for example

Main view script (remove the `onchange` attribute from the `DropDownList()` helper)

```
var url = '@Url.Action("Course")';
var holes = $('#CourseHoles');
$('#Courses').change(function() {
  holes.load(url, { ID: $(this).val() });
}
```

Controller

```
public ActionResult Course(int ID)
{
  Record model = new Record();
  // Populate the model based on the course ID (for example)
  model.RecordHoles = db.RecordHoles.Where(c => c.CourseID == ID).ToList();
  return PartialView("_Holes", model);
}
```

PartialView (_Holes.cshtml)

```
@model Golf_Statz.Models.Record
@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RecordHoles)
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot render a view/part through javascript/jQuery (`$('#CourseHoles').Html(@Html.EditorFor(m => m.RecordHoles));`).

Pre-render the input in the `div`, hide it, and use `show()` to show it in the function.

```
function DropDownChange(dd) {
    $('#CourseHoles').empty();
    $('#CourseHoles').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function DropDownChange(course){
   var url = 'yourUrl';
   $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: {id: $(course).val()},
      dataType: "json",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(data)
      {
         // update your DOM here
      }
   });
}
```